# Parse config file and create json object using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a directory of config files, each config file has a line like this:

`DOMAIN domainname.com`

I need to be able to extract everything after `DOMAIN` and store it in a json object.

I can match the line I need like this:

`d = re.findall(^DOMAIN.*, mystring)`

I can add that to a dict like this:

```
dict = {
       "config": {
            "domains": [
               d,
            ]
        }
}
```

This works but only for the first `DOMAIN`.  How would I find all occurrences of `DOMAIN` and add it to the `domains` array?

Comment: What do you mean by "only for the first DOMAIN"? What other DOMAINs are there?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, only one additional attribute is required. `domains = re.findall(r'^DOMAIN\s+(.*)$', mystring, flags=re.M)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all these domain config files are in a `config` dir whcih only contains files with a single line like `DOMAIN <domain>`, you could do something like this:

```
import os

domains = []
for file in os.listdir('./config'):
    with open(file) as f:
        _, d = f.read().strip().split()
        domains.append(d)
```

then you set the value of `domains` inside this dictionnary